# C read txt file line by line and write contents as one line into another txt file

Tags: c, file

I want to read a txt file, line by line, and each line stores in a different variable: here is the txt file I want to read:

```
java javascript
python
c c++
```

I want to write content of that txt file into another txt file as one line:

```
java javascript python c c++
```

Here is my implemented code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // read any text file from currect directory
    char const *const fileName = "cppbuzz1.txt";
    char ch;
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    FILE *fout;
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("\n Unable to open : %s ", fileName);
        return -1;
    }

    fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    ch = fgetc(file);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        fputc(ch, fout);
        ch = fgetc(file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot get desired output file. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the part where you are actually filtering the newline characters out...

Comment: Also you should close *both* files.

Comment: I couldn't recognize it

Comment: Recognize what? Newline characters? You are using them in your output right here: ` `printf("\n... <-- `

Comment: how I cancel new line character because source file has already new lines

Comment: Just don't copy it...

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`.  If you declare `ch` as type `char`, you lose information.  In particular, if the file contains `0xff`, your code will (on most platforms) incorrectly terminate early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter line break

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // read any text file from currect directory
    char const *const fileName = "cppbuzz1.txt";
    char ch;
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    FILE *fout;
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("\n Unable to open : %s ", fileName);
        return -1;
    }

    fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    ch = fgetc(file);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        //change line break to space
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            fputc(' ', fout);
        }
        else
        {
            fputc(ch, fout);
        }
        ch = fgetc(file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(fout); //close output file
    return 0;
}
```